# Is this phrase implied in a good way?

Tags: meaning, phrases

The phrase is "this is beyond uninspired".
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Probably not, but it's hard to be sure without seeing the context.

Comment: This sentence has someone reply me when I offer something to him.

Comment: But the full phrase is "Please, no! This is uninspired"

Comment: **uninspired** means _there are no original or exciting qualities._    "Beyond uninspired" is emphasising that whatever it is, is  dull or ordinary or unimaginative

Comment: When used in sentences of the type you are talking about, "beyond" is an intensifier—indeed a stronger intensifier than "very." So if you say "beyond good," the phrase means "better than good" (in other words, outstanding); but if you say "beyond bad," the phrase means "worse than bad" (in other words, execrable). And since "uninspired" is not a compliment, to call something "beyond uninspired" is to say that it is utterly lacking in creative spark.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the modifier 'beyond' before an a adjective to indicate that the adjective is insufficient for the purpose, or that heavy intensification of the adjective is intended (like using "very"). "Beyond uninspired" means that the thing being described is very dull, uninteresting, unoriginal, etc, indeed, so that a stronger word is needed.

> Beyond excited, serious, angry, etc. ​ informal extremely excited,
>   serious, angry, etc.:
>
> She says she is beyond excited to see her son for the first time in
>   more than three years. These days, I'm beyond happy.

[Beyond (Cambridge)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/beyond)